# How to extract specific data in results obtained from using Python Requests library

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-requests, django-2.1, github-api-v3

Please take a look at the code below:

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    code = request.GET.get('code', '')
    payload = {
        "client_id" : settings.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
        "client_secret" : settings.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
        "code" : code,
        "state" : settings.STATE,
    }
    response = requests.post('https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token', params=payload)
    # final_response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=GitHubTokenAuth(access_token))
    return HttpResponse(response)
    # authenticated_user = final_response.json()
    # return render(request, 'core/dashboard.html', {'authenticated_user':authenticated_user})
```

The `response` variable is returning values similar to:

```
access_token=eiwfbvdsvefieebrferferwfreferfersfwrb&scope=a%20list%20of%20scopes&token_type=bearer
```

How do I access the value of `access_token` so I can use as seen in the value of the commented out `final_response` variable?
Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) method of `urllib`:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import parse_qs
>>> parse_qs(response.text)
{'access_token': ['eiwfbvdsvefieebrferferwfreferfersfwrb'], 'scope': ['a list of scopes'], 'token_type': ['bearer']}
```

Note that you will get a `list` for each key. To access the first element, use the following syntax:

```
>>> result = parse_qs(response.text)
>>> result['access_token'][0]
'eiwfbvdsvefieebrferferwfreferfersfwrb'
```